# Painting over already painted plank walls, do I need to sand it before?

Tags: wood, painting, repainting

We're living in a 200+ years old house, slowly renovating, and we're starting the second floor which is basically wood plank walls. Some of them have wallpaper on it, but most of them are painted.

Now Googling here and there, the only source I've found that mentioned plank wall there where already painted said to "sand the wall to remove old  paint" before painting over.

Now my walls already have *at least* two layer of old paint and I feel link sanding it will take us forever... Would sanding it really be needed? Can't I just paint over the old paint?

Comment: You should determine whether there is any lead paint on any walls that you would sand. Where is this property located?

Comment: @JimStewart In Quebec, Canada.

Comment: You should contact the appropriate regulatory authority. I'm sure they will tell you what you need to do. If there is lead paint present, you may be allowed to paint over it. In this case I would apply a good interior primer, then finish paint over that. Latex interior finish paint would probably not adhere if applied directly to the paint already there. A guy I know who is dedicated to a quality job was having his house painted prior to selling it. He had the painters apply oil-based Kilz primer on the old paint, and then finish paint on top of that.

Comment: I actually went to see the old owner of the house who now lives down the street, and he said he was almost certain that there has to be some lead painting somewhere under all of the layers. But I'll have yes to check with the authorities to know what to do. According to the last owner, the last layer was latex, and what I bought is 2 in 1 paint+primer, latex painting. Should be ok with this. Really just need to check if I'm legally bound to remove anything before!

Comment: You should check on this, but my understanding is that you do not have to remove any old paint, but that if you would want to sand you would have to follow a procedure that would not lead to lead dust being created. If I were you I would start painting in a closet to see if the paint adheres properly before plunging into the main part of the job.